# Validation Status

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to do a status validation with nodejs and mongodb, if the status is "unverified" I should not be able to access, however if the status is "verified" it allows me to access the account. note: The state is saved in the database

My verification code is this (controller)

```
exports.usuario_verify = function (req, res) { 
  let usuario = req.body.username;
  let pass = req.body.password;
  let datos = "Usuario: " + usuario + " Pass: " + pass;
  if (usuario && pass) {
    //Hay datos en usuario y password
    User.find({ Username: usuario, Password: pass }, function (error, results) {
      if (error) {
        let data = {
          title: "Ingreso al sistema",
          message: "Hubo un error contacte a soporte",
        };
        res.render("login", data);
      }

      if (results.length > 0) {
        let roles;
        results.forEach((element) => {
          roles = element.Roles;
        });
        req.session.usuario = usuario;
        req.session.role = roles;
        if (roles === "admin") {
          res.render("admin_home");
        } else if (roles === "user") {
          res.render("coleccion"); //next();
        }
      } else {
        let data = {
          title: "Ingreso al sistema",
          message: "Usuario o contraseña no son correctos",
        };
        res.render("login", data);
      }
    });
  } else {
    let data = {
      title: "Ingreso al sistema",
      message: "Usuario o contraseña no son correctos",
    };
    res.render("login", data);
   
    
}};

exports.usuario_add = function (req, res) {
  res.send("Ruta controlada");
};
```

I am trying to do a status validation with nodejs and mongodb, if the status is "unverified" I should not be able to access, however if the status is "verified" it allows me to access the account. note: The state is saved in the database

Comment: Soooo, what exactly is your question here? Are you getting an error? If so, post it. Your question is very vague and I'm not sure how we could help...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the `isValidated` field at user collection of db and then create the middleware using it. Thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).